# ck editor adding html tags on the browser while showing to the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

**Current Requirenment :**

I am having a form if users fill the form there will be a **button to export form**  as word and if he clicks the form will get downloaded as word.

[image]

**Issue:**

I am using ck editor in one field to the form ,  I am  entering the text and using the tools that is provided in the `ckeditor` such as `bold italics`, `bullets [B,I]` etc while I am exporting the form to pdf I am seeing `html` tags appended in the exported word docs.

**Needed:**
I need the exported document to be viewed as plain text without any html tags

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this really, but we can't help without a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this issue , the main mistake in the word template i gave the same variable name for two place which over rides and provide html tags(not parsing) , if the name is changed to two different names the probem is solved